# "No such file or directory" error while running pyq in Ubuntu with 32 bit kdb+

Tags: ubuntu, kdb, pyq

I have installed pyq by following the instruction from https://pyq.enlnt.com/install/install.html#install.

I created a virtualenv py2 and downloaded kdb+ from https://kx.com/download/software-download.L.php?agree=willa382*-fyeERA332880aa2013 and unpacked it inside py2

```
unzip /home/username/Downloads/linuxx86.zip -d py2
```

Then installed pyq

```
pip install -i https://pyq.enlnt.com --no-binary pyq pyq
```

After that I typed

```
pyq
```

Now I am getting the following error

```
qbinpath = /home/usename/py2/q/l64/q
qbinpath = /home/username/q/l64/q
No such file or directory
```

I have searched for the qbinpath variable. It is inside a binary file at location

```
 /home/username/pyq/path/to/virtualenv/bin/pyq
```

As such I am unable to run pyq in ubuntu.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run PyQ, you need to have Python and kdb+ of matching architectures installed.  From your description, it appears that you have a standard 64-bit Python and attempt to use it with the free 32-bit edition of kdb+.  This does not work and `pyq` rightfully complains that it cannot find an "l64" version of q in various directories.

Building a 32-bit Python on a 64-bit host Linux for use with the free kdb+ can be a challenge and we only have [instructions for CentOS 7](https://pyq.enlnt.com/install/install.html#installing-32-bit-pyq-with-the-free-32-bit-kdb-and-python-3-6-on-64-bit-centos-7).

It may be easier to use a 32-bit VM with a 32-bit Ubuntu if you want to use PyQ and don't have a kdb+ license.

Comment: Thank You. I will try it

Comment: I installed a 32 bit Ubuntu and installed pyq and it worked

Answer (score 1):

set the QHOME to the top level folder, that has m32/q in it and then start pyq.

Comment: Would you like to improve your answer by augmenting it with an explanation?